# Converting LC-3 into C

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert LC-3's ADD and AND assembly language instructions into machine code via a C program.

The file with instructions named source.txt contains the following:

```
add r1,r2,r3
and r0,r4,r5
```

My code at the moment is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int number = 0;
    int shift = 16;
    int instruction = 0;
    char input[50];

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("source.txt", "r");
    //finding if the file exists
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file\n");
        return(0);
    }

    while (fgets(input, 50, fp) != NULL){
        char *token;
        char delim[4] = (" ,\n");

        token = strtok(input, delim);

        int count = 0;
        while (token != NULL){
            if (count == 3){
                shift = shift - 3;
            }

            if (strcmp(token, "add") == 0){
                number = 0x1000;
                shift = 12;
            }

            if (strcmp(token, "and") == 0){
                number = 0x5000;
                shift = 12;
            }

            else if (strcmp(token, "r0") == 0){
                //Do nothing as number is originally padded with 0's
                //shift = shift - 3 skips shifting the 3 0's
            }

            else if (strcmp(token, "r1") == 0){
                instruction = 0x0001 << shift;
                number = number | instruction;
            }

            else if (strcmp(token, "r2") == 0){
                instruction = 0x0002 << shift;
                number = number | instruction;
            }

            else if (strcmp(token, "r3") == 0){
                instruction = 0x0003 << shift;
                number = number | instruction;
            }

            else if (strcmp(token, "r4") == 0){
                instruction = 0x0004 << shift;
                number = number | instruction;
            }

            else if (strcmp(token, "r5") == 0){
                instruction = 0x0005 << shift;
                number = number | instruction;
            }

            else if (strcmp(token, "r6") == 0){
                instruction = 0x0006 << shift;
                number = number | instruction;
            }

            else if (strcmp(token, "r7") == 0){
                instruction = 0x0007 << shift;
                number = number | instruction;
            }

            shift = shift - 3;
            count++;
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        printf("%x", number);
        printf("%s\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The current output is:

```
1280
5105
```

The desired output is:

```
1283
5105
```

I can't figure out why the first value is slightly off.

Comment: What is your code even doing...? You're assigning random things for adds and ands, and registers don't even have values by default. This is extremely offtopic and unclear. Please edit it and actually add what your reasoning is behind having all of those conditions like that because it's unclear to anyone who doesn't specifically know LC3 (or even those of us like myself who do, but have no idea wtf you're doing)

Comment: Did you consult with your debugger? It should be kindof trivial to inspect the intermediate values and taken code paths for the `"r3"` loop iteration

Comment: By the way: my output with your code equals your desired output (+some noise because of the `printf("%s\n");`) so you may want to re-check the content of your `source.txt` and whether your code really equals the question code.